# how to output lowercase unicode in WebHelpers.ConvertToJson

Tags: php, json, vba, unicode

I have an online service that uses MD5s of JSON-encoded REQUEST objects as a form of verification that the object that is sent over POST is the object that is received, and has not been edited or truncated in transit.

We have come across a problem when working with clients written in VBA, which convert UTF characters to uppercase unicode when converted to JSON through WebHelpers.ConvertToJson

For example, in PHP, json_encode("£") will return '\u00a3', but in VBA, WebHelpers.ConvertToJson('£') will return '\u00A3'.

When I MD5 those two strings, the MD5s are obviously very different.

So, my question is - how do I set WebHelpers.ConvertToJson to output lowercase unicode?

Or, how would I translate a JSON string after the conversion to lowercase the unicode?